# python make sure that word is capitalized

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make sure that every word that is typed **is** uppercased as in ABC. The code I'm working with is this

```
abbreviate=input("Abbreviation: ")
words=abbreviate[0:6]
numbers = abbreviate[6:8]
if len(abbreviate)==9:
    if words.isalpha: #I think it's also possible to use.if str(words)?
        if words.isupper: #(i did upper first, what is the difference?)
            if int(numbers):
                print("correct")
            else:
                 print("wrong, you need numbers")
        else:
             print("wrong, all words are supposed to be uppercase")
    else:
         print("wrong, it needs to be words(alphabet)") 
else:
     print("wrong, the length needs to be 8")
```

QWERTY567 should be correct.
qwerty567 should be incorrect.
How do I go on doing this?

qwerty333
012345678

Comment: Although the `if-else` clause seems rather straightforward, if you could explain the logic in the question it would be helpful when formulating an answer!

Comment: You forgot `()` in `isalpha()`, `isupper()`

Comment: If the value of abbreviate is 'QWERTY567', then you should edit your code with  `words = abbreviate[0:6]` , `numbers = abbreviate[6:8]` , `isalpha()` and `isupper` for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

[`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) and [`str.isupper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) are *methods*. You need to call them to get a result:

```
if words.isalpha():
    if words.isupper():
```

---

#### About your comments

> I think it's also possible to use `if str(words)`?

No, `str(words)` would do nothing. [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string, so `words` is already a string.

> I did `upper` first, what is the difference?

[`str.upper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) *converts* a string to uppercase, e.g. `'a'.upper() == 'A'`

---

#### By the way

`int()` doesn't return a Boolean. It might be better to use [`str.isnumeric`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) to check if `numbers` is numeric instead.

It's simpler to use guard clauses than nested conditionals:

```
if len(abbreviate) != 9:
    print("wrong, the length needs to be 9")
elif not words.isalpha():
    print("wrong, the abbreviation must be alphabetic")
...
else:
    print("correct")
```

Comment: IIRC `str.isnumeric()` doesn't cover all possible strings that can be cast to int, right? That may not be an issue here, but it's good to keep in mind.

Comment: @amc Yes, `int()` will allow a plus/minus sign and leading/trailing whitespace. Plus `str.isnumeric()` covers some strings that can't be cast to int, like Roman numerals. But I think `str.isnumeric()` is closer to what OP wants, though maybe a regex like `[0-9]+` would be better. Anyway I left this info off the answer cause it's beside the point and I didn't want to explain try-except or regex.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC In order to just verify, whether first 5 characters are uppercase letters, and next 4 are digits, you can do:

```py
import re

abbreviate=input("Abbreviation: ")

if(re.match(r"^[A-Z]{5}\d{4}", abbreviate)):
    print("correct!")
else:
    print("wrong!")
```

If moreover you want to ensure it's only 9 characters in total (i.e. input consists of exactly 5 uppercase letters first, then 4 digits) you can do:

```py
import re

abbreviate=input("Abbreviation: ")

if(re.match(r"^[A-Z]{5}\d{4}$", abbreviate)):
    print("correct!")
else:
    print("wrong!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
^[A-Z0-9]+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lU2ny9/1).

Answer (score 0):

If you have all letters and then at a certain index, you have all numbers, I would suggest:

```
abbreviation=input("Abbreviation: ")
i = len(abbreviation)
for n, char in enumerate(abbreviation):
    if char.isalpha() and char.isupper():
        pass
    else:
        i = n
        break
for char in abbreviation[i:]:
    if char.isnumeric():
        pass
    else:
        print('Wrong')
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-isnumeric-application/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/isupper-islower-lower-upper-python-applications/

You find the first non-lowercase letter, and then everything after it should be all numeric. If you need at least 1 uppercase letter, you can also modify that. Please tell me if you have questions!

Answer (score 0):

If the value of abbreviate is 'QWERTY567', then you should edit your code with  `words = abbreviate[0:6]` , `numbers = abbreviate[6:8]` , `isalpha()` and `isupper()` for it to work.